# Accessing KRB5CCNAME from /etc/gdm/PreSession/Default on RHEL8

Tags: pam, gnome, rhel8, gdmgreeting

I would like to run a script after a user login. This script, using his kerberos tickets, will mount an SMB share.

Under RedHat 7 I could simply call the script from `/etc/gdm/PreSession/Default` and it would run fine. It would even preserve the `$KRB5CCNAME` when running the script while elevated (this variable is kept via a `Defaults env_keep += "KRB5CCNAME"` under `sudoers.d`.

Under Ubuntu 18.04 we use a service under `/etc/systemd/user`, which would use the ticket whenever there is a ticket.

With other words, under RHEL7 and Ubuntu, we could use the tickets even when elevated via sudo, either by running a user service or by calling the script from `/etc/gdm/PreSession/Default`.

Under RHEL8 we can't see the variable, neither when running the user service, nor when running it when calling it from `/etc/gdm/PreSession/Default`. When I log in as the user, I can see the variable, even when using `sudo`, so the environment variable is kept, but somehow it isn't available for the service nor for that script.

Could anyone help me how to fix this? I think I read somewhere that this might have something to do with how `gdm` is started under rhel8, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

UPDATE: I see now that the scripts under `/etc/gdm/PreSession/Default` execute as `root`. I had the impression that they were executed as the user.

UPDATE2: It seems that I can use tickets anyway. I was assuming that they were not there, just because the `$KRB5CCNAME` was unset. But running a command that required the tickets worked anyway.